# ms-Access Not using combo box display values as the lookup value

Tags: vba, ms-access

**NOTE**
*I significantly edited my original post to include more relevant information and removed insignificant information. Some of the comments are based on the information removed, but the integrity of the original question is still intact and the comments are still relevant and useful.*

In my database I have a table `tblStandards` that has a list of compound names with their associated fields.
I created a form to generate a subform which only populates compound names and their data when you select a solution mixture (I called these "handles"). I am using this subform as a means of generating a "Location Finder" of all the respective compounds associated with that solution mixture "handle". The issue is some compounds are used in multiple different mixtures, thus having multiple "handles". I have included a cascading combo box as recommended by @June7, but I am running into an issue with the last combo box filter.

I don’t want to have a separate field attached to my `tblStandards` with the combo box display value ("handle") just to filter my table (which is what I have done in the past). Using combo box display value field in my table works but it is limited and I wish to make it more modular. I have a second table `tblComboBox` which has three fields; [Compound Name], [Standard_InternalStd], and [Cal_QC_Handle].

I have the cascading combo box working, except for last filter. I think I found a round-about way to filter based on my tables. I am using an After_Update event with the  `FilterOn` function to filter a `TempSubform` which is filtering the `tblComboBox` based on matching the [Cal_QC_Handle] to the `cboxSecondChoice`, then using `TempSubform![Compound Names]` field as a second `FilterOn` function for my `MainSubform`.
My code is working, but the second `FilterOn` is only using the first Compound Name from my `TempSubform` to filter `MainSubform`. I want to filter based on all the rows in my `Tempsubform.[Compound Name]`. I think my issue is in my  `" & Me.Temsubform![Compound Name] &"` block of code.

```
Private Sub cboxSecondChoice_AfterUpdate()

Dim Filter_Tempsubform As String
Filter_Tempsubform = "[Cal_QC_Handle] ='" & Me.cboxSecondChoice & "'"
Forms![Standards_Form]![TempSubform].Form.FilterOn = False
Forms![Standards_Form]![TempSubform].Form.Filter = Filter_Tempsubform
Forms![Standards_Form]![TempSubform].Form.FilterOn = True

Dim Filter_MainSubform As String
Filter_MainSubform = "[Compound Name] = '" & Me.TempSubform![Compound Name] & "'"
Forms![Standards_Form]![MainSubform].Form.FilterOn = False
Forms![Standards_Form]![MainSubform].Form.Filter = Filter_MainSubform
Forms![Standards_Form]![MainSubform].Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

The issue is the filter is only using one Compound Name (the first on the list) to filter. I need the filter to use ***all*** the Compound Names from the newly filtered TempSubform. Apologies if this is a very convoluted approach. Every example that I have seen so far always has the combo box value embedded in the table that they are filtering, which is something I wish to avoid.

**UPDATE**

I have abandoned my 1st attempt (the double FilterOn function with a temporary Subform) and I have a working form! I had to modify my `tblStandards` to include a new field which contained values from my final combobox selection (which I wanted to circumvent initially due to my perceived limitations of this design). The new `Form-Handle` field on my table is a string with multiple single "handles" which I use if the final combobox selection (only a single "handle" can be selected) is in the subform using the wildcard "Like *". Each one of these "handles" corresponds to a solution mixture which is a specific list of compounds.

This solution allows me to have a single compound used to make multiple different solutions, and if you select any of these solutions to make from the dropdown combo box the compound will be returned. I think this is the simplest solution to my issue and I might have just been too stubborn looking for a over-complicated solution.

I modified code from [Allen Browne's ms-Access "Filter a Form on a Field in a Subform"](http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html)

[Relationships (All)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nywCF.png)

[Form with cascading comboboxes and filter button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx1nQ.png)

[Working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKDqI.png)

Comment: I cannot imagine an alternative to lookup table. Based on what I think you want to do, that's what they're for. Although, it's not entirely clear to me exactly what your issue is.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in my original post, but I don't know how to code or use the combo box properties to make the combo box display values reference a list of other values to filter a subform. e.g. from above, I would like the combo box to display the options "Standard"; "Internal Standard"; "Misc.", and each of these options would pull corresponding values from a lookup table `tblComboBoxFilterValues` to be used to filter my subform. I only know how to make the combobox filter if the display value is actually present in the subform.

Comment: That sounds like what is know as 'cascading' combobox - a very common topic. A combobox offers list of broad categories and then another combobox list is filtered depending on choice in first combobox. Do some research and make an effort. A little VBA is needed.

Comment: Thank you @June7, I did not know the name. I will check out the tutorials that eckman has provided! I would like to attempt some VBA as well, so I'll give that a go and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @June7 said, cascading ComboBoxes (or ListBoxes) are the standard UI design for multistage filtering of data tables. If I have the available form real estate, I prefer cascading ListBoxes over ComboBoxes, because of the visual cues they provide. For example, look at how [Digi-Key does it](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/aluminum-polymer-capacitors/69). Problems with cascading ComboBoxes have been questioned to death [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D%20cascading%20combobox). Boxes which filter data, list or combo, are usually *unbound*, and should *not* be simultaneously used to *update* data. Their sole purpose is to display item choices, select an item, and pass it's value to the next filter.

I'm linking below to a few tutorials, which require little to no VBA code. The 3rd tutorial filters "plants and animals, categorized by their taxonomic rank", which is a similar case to filtering chemical compounds. The 4th is one of my previous answers to a similar question.

- [Microsoft Access: How to Create Cascading Combo Boxes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFSvnT9LHn0)
- [Access 2016 - How to Make a City/State Selector (Cascading Combo
  Boxes)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ljoKaS6M9Q&t=352s)
- [Creating Cascading Combo Boxes and List Boxes on Microsoft Access
  Forms](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/forms/combo-boxes/cascading.html)
- [Creating Cascading Comboxes in VBA code using RowSource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67099208/13486190)

Comment: In the third link (filtering plants and animals), if I am understanding their code correctly, they updated the `lstSpeciesID.RowSource` by setting the field `KingdomID` equal to the selection in the final combo box `cboKingdomID`?
In my case, my final combo box value is NOT located in the subform I wish to filter, unlike the example provided where the cboKingdomID is actually located in the KingomID field within their table or `qryTaxonomy`.

Comment: My last combo box values (CAL-QC) are being pulled from a table which only has 3 fields; Compound Name, Standard-InternalStandard, and CAL-QC. I want to use the last combo box value to pull the associated Compound Name field, then use the Compound Name to filter my subform. My subform is pulling data from a table that has >10 fields and none of them have the exact value from the final combo box.

Comment: I added an update to my original post. Thank you for the help @eckman with the cascading combo boxes, and June7 as well. I think I found a work-around to my latest issue with the last combo box filtering, but I think I have the wrong syntax?

Comment: @Ari I just read your message. I've been busy. I'm sure your problem description makes sense in your head, because you can see the whole application. Can you please add screen shots of your table relationships, Standards_Form with MainSubform visible, and cboxSecondChoice expanded ("dropped" down)?

Comment: @Ari I've had a little more time to review this. I agree with you. Your solution is "convoluted". Relational databases need to follow specific structures and rules to behave as expected. You can bend the rules a little, but not a lot. I've updated my answer with a new link to one of my previous answers which demonstrates how to filter cascading ComboBoxes in VBA code.

Comment: I will edit my post to include the screen shots requested. The 4th link that you posted (2nd design choice) is actually what I am currently using as a work around. I have abandoned my convoluted "double FilterOn function" scheme. And no worries about "timely" responses! You and June7 have been a great help and I do have a very workable form which we just put into use this last week, it is just not exactly how I wanted to accomplish it. I actually think it might be better the way I have it vs what I was originally trying to do. I will include this code as well.

Comment: @Ari Better :-)